# How to pass MIP gap parameter to Gurobi with PULP

Tags: python, python-3.x, gurobi, pulp

How to pass MIP gap parameter to Gurobi with PULP?

I tried: 
prob.solve(GUROBI_CMD(epgap = 0.9))

No luck

[I used this wiki for all my failed attempts](https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/solvers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, i would assume, that you have to give the arguments as defined in [gurobi's docs](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/refman/parameters.html#sec:Parameters) (these are then passed when calling gurobi's cli), compatible with pulp's function-signature.

```
prob.solve(GUROBI_CMD(options=['MIPGap=0.9']))
```

But i probably recommend using the python-interface if you got gurobipy working (read gurobi's docs). This would look like:

```
prob.solve(GUROBI(epgap = 0.9))
```

Comment: Thanks sascha, prob.solve(GUROBI(epgap = 0.9)) worked!